# R - find rows corresponding to maximum value of a column among mutliple rows

Tags: r, dplyr

with data like below, have data for hours of each day for each `area,loc` pair. Need to find out the rows for each `area,loc` for which value of `a` is maximum.

```
day,hour,area,loc,a,b,c
20181231,ar01,loc01,00,99,11.3,18.2
20181231,ar01,loc01,22,96,12.3,15.2
20190101,ar01,loc01,00,98,10.9,22.5
20190101,ar01,loc01,23,97,10.9,22.1
20181231,ar02,loc01,00,93,11.3,18.2
20181231,ar02,loc01,22,96,12.3,15.2
20190101,ar02,loc01,00,97,10.9,22.5
20190101,ar02,loc01,23,97.2,10.9,22.1
```

expected output

```
day,hour,area,loc,a,b,c
20181231,ar01,loc01,00,99,11.3,18.2
20190101,ar01,loc01,00,98,10.9,22.5
20181231,ar02,loc01,22,96,12.3,15.2
20190101,ar02,loc01,23,97.2,10.9,22.1
```

I could do an aggregation using dplyr, like `df %>% group_by(day, area, loc)` - how do I get the result rows from here ?

Comment: `df %>% group_by(day, area, loc) %>% slice(which.max(a))`

Comment: @RonakShah, just a quick question, does `filter` is not providing the same output than `slice` ? Does there is any difference ?

Comment: @dc37 because when you are comparing values with `==` in `filter` in case of tie it will return all the rows which are equal to maximum value whereas when we use `which.max` in `slice` it will return only the first maximum. This example may clarify. `x <- c(1:5, 5)` and compare output of `which.max(x == 5)` and `which(x == 5)`

Comment: @RonakShah, thanks for this clarification. Based on the question, I'm not sure which one between `filter` or `slice` will solve the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(day, area, loc) %>%
   filter(., a == max(a))
```